# Where to put partial specific javascript in rails 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

Consider the following partial, it gets inserted into a page if someone clicks AJAX "add comment" link.  The question I have is: Is this the best place to include that JavaScript?

I thought it was best to put it in the application.js, but because the partial gets added via AJAX, the validate method called within `$(document).ready` block does not get triggered because the form does not exist when the original document is ready.  Does that make sense?

Using Rails 2.3.4 and jQuery 1.4.1

Thanks!

```
<%form_for [@commentable,@comment] do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, :class=>"required", :minlength=>2%>

  <% content_tag :button, :type => :submit do %>
    Comment
  <% end %>
<%end%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_comment").validate();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when you want the validation to occur, but it seems like you could use jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functionality to attack a validation method defined in your **application.js** to the incoming partial's submit button.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
$("#new_comment").live('click', function(event) {
  $(this).validate();
  // or maybe event.target.validate(); ?
});
```

Comment: what would the syntax of that be?  I found http://api.jquery.com/live/ but unclear how to apply it in this situation.  $("#new_comment").live('validate'); in application.js does not seem to work

Comment: This was the syntax that I got it to work with:

$("#new_comment").live('click', function() {
    $(this).validate();
});

Comment: Glad it worked! I updated the answer to reflect the syntax that was used.